# Fill temp table after check results in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have the following approach:

The first check is, are data not from US:

```
WITH Step1 AS (
        SELECT 
            t1.IdentNo, 
            t1.Name 
        FROM 
            dbo.Table1 t1 
        WHERE 
            t1.CCode <> 'US'
    ),

Step2 AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            t2.IdentNo, 
            t2.Name
        FROM
            dbo.Table2 t2
        INNER JOIN
            Step1 s1
        ON
            t2.IdentNo = s1.IdentNo
        WHERE
            (t2.artNo='AB504' AND t2.VALUE='1')
    )

-- TEST RESULT  
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        Step2
```

So, the solution need to be, in the first step I want to add all `IdentNo`-s in a temp table. Then in the second step I want to update the temp table with the value "1" for all returned `IdentNo`-s.

The temp table would be defined like so:

```
IdentNo | Name | Step1 | Step2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include your step1.name in step2 cte is what you are looking for, please check below code

```
;WITH Step1 AS (
        SELECT 
            t1.IdentNo, 
            t1.Name 
        FROM 
            dbo.Table1 t1 
        WHERE 
            t1.CCode <> 'US'
    ),

Step2 AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            t2.IdentNo, 
            t2.Name as [Step2Name],
            s1.Name as [Step1Name]
        FROM
            dbo.Table2 t2
        INNER JOIN
            Step1 s1
        ON
            t2.IdentNo = s1.IdentNo
        WHERE
            (t2.artNo='AB504' AND t2.VALUE='1')
    )

-- TEST RESULT  
    SELECT
        IdentNo, Step1Name as Name, Step1Name as Step1, Step2Name as Step2
    FROM
        Step2
```

Still not clear what Name you are looking for

Comment: I need a column Step1 and Step2 which displays true or false.. true = the IdentNo is available in the Step result.